# Image validation in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How do I write a Image validation format that makes sure url ends with either .png, .jpg  or .gif ?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :image_url

  validates :title, :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => true
  validates :image_url, :presence => true,
                        :format => {
                           :with => %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i,
                           :message => 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
                        }
end
```

i tried this but its not working.

Thanks,
Mezbah

Comment: Your code is correct.Can you tell me what is not working? Did you get any error?

Comment: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?